# Can't open Eclipse anymore - Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

When i try to start Eclipse (on Windows) i get this error, out of nowhere:

> Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

And:

> Java was started but returned exit code = 1

[image]

My attempts to solve the problem:

- Editing the eclipse.ini with `-Xms3072M -Xmx6144M XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` (and other combinations).
- Adding a path before -vmargs, such as `-vm “c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\javaw.exe”`
- Changing `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6` with 1.7 (i have multiple jdk and jre, in *Program Files/Java* and *Program Files(x86)/Java*).
- Deleting eclipse.ini.
- Adding the following system environment variables: _JAVA_OPTION (-Xmx512M), JAVA_HOME. And editing Path with a path from my jdk7.
- Restarting the system at every step.

Comment: You're using unsupported Java versions but besides that have you tried to reboot?  Windows memory can get scattered and the JVM can't always handle that.

Comment: What Eclipse version are you trying to run? Current Eclipse requires JDK 11 and 64 bit systems: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation

Comment: @akarnokd Eclipse Kepler. This morning there was no problems with Eclipse, default eclipse.ini and my project with jdk7.

Comment: @stdunbar I tried to reboot several times. Why unsupported Java versions?

Comment: @akarnokd - based on the screenshot it appears to be a version from 2013.

Comment: @akarnokd Yes, 2013, so jdk6-7 are supported

Comment: Java 7 hasn't been supported for a while.  You're using a version of Eclipse that is 9 years old.  The version of Java you're using was released about 10 years ago.  These are prehistoric in the Java world.

Comment: Use the current Eclipse 2022-06 to code which still supports Java versions from 6 and even older up to Java 18. Make sure to configure the Java you want  to use in the preferences _Java > Installed JREs_. Don't use outdated software like Java 7 or Eclipse Kepler (you failed doing retrocomputing by [incorrectly editing `eclipse.ini`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment section, installing a new version of Eclipse (Photon, 2022-06 or more) solved the problem.